# Из-за чего может произойти ошибка

Tags: python

После if стоит : и выдаёт ошибку SyntaxError invalid syntax  язык: Python

```
a = 0
a = input ("")
b = float ( input (""))
c = float ( input (""))

if  a==+:
summa = b + c
print (summa)
elif a==-:
summa = b - c
print (summa)
elif a==*:
summa = b * c
print (summa)
else a==/:
summa = b / c
print (summa)
```

Comment: Отступы не соблюдены у вас, почитайте о них, в питоне это критично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = input ("")
b = float ( input (""))
c = float ( input (""))

if  a=="+":
    summa = b + c
    print (summa)
elif a=="-":
    summa = b - c
    print (summa)
elif a=="*":
    summa = b * c
    print (summa)
elif a=="/":
    summa = b / c
    print (summa)
```

Comment: Странно при + ответ пишется  а при другом операторе не пишет ответ